# KeyError: 'render_modes' while creating an env in openai-gym

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

[IMG of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQIYO.png)

I'm trying to create a stock trading environment for my reinforcement model but unable to create it due to the error.

I've tried so far: Deleted all the parameters,
tried to set render_mode="Human" and "rgb_array" and "True" none of these work,
downgraded gym to 0.24.1

[img of whole code in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkLTz.png)

I don't understand what's the problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, it was in issue gym-anytrading not being compatible with newer version of gym.

In this [line](https://github.com/AminHP/gym-anytrading/blob/master/gym_anytrading/envs/trading_env.py#L24) of code, change render.modes to render_modes. Got the fix from the gym-anytrading creator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).